# JDBC sql server driver installation in kakfa - image wurstmeister/kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am in the progress of syncing a sql server table to Snowflake. I might use kafka for this and found a docker image - wurstmeister/kafka from the docker hub. 
I have cloned the repository wurstmeister/kafka-docker  and ran the docker-compose up -d from the folder where it's cloned. Everything is fine until here. I want to now go to the next step ie.

1. how to install jdbc from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57782) into the image, in the docker file? what path in the container? This is to connect the sql server table and run the sql statement to get the changed rows.
2. How to set up the connection, which file
3. Do I need a kakfak connect image as well, if so how to do that , I assume it would be in the yml file?
4. Is there a log where I can see if the connection went fine.

These are the questions in my mind and I am pretty stuck. I would really appreciate any help or pointer.

Comment: ,The question is not brief about real fact of the issue . Please elaborate little clear and share it

Answer (score 2):

> This is to connect the sql server table and run the sql statement to get the changed rows.

I would recommend using Kafka Connect to ingest data from a database. For that there is the Kafka Connect image (along with others) at https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/

For SQL Server specifically you have three options:

- [JDBC Source connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/)
- [SQL Server CDC connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql/) (Confluent)
- [SQL Server CDC connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/debezium-sql-server-cdc-connector/) (Debezium)

> how to install jdbc from here into the image, in the docker file? what path in the container?

You can build your own docker image with the connector baked in, or you can install it as part of running it. This article discusses [deploying a connector automatically](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/).

> How to set up the connection, which file

Each connector will have its own configuration requirements. Broadly speaking though you use the Kafka Connect REST API to configure it (or a properties file, in standalone mode).

> Do I need a kakfak connect image as well, if so how to do that , I assume it would be in the yml file?

For that there is the Kafka Connect image (along with others) at https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/

> Is there a log where I can see if the connection went fine.

Kafka Connect worker writes logs to stdout by default, which you can view through docker logs. See [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector) for an example of working with Kafka Connect and the JDBC connector

> These are the questions in my mind and I am pretty stuck. I would really appreciate any help or pointer.

Kafka Connect is where you need to be looking. It can act as both a source (get data into Kafka) and sink (get data from Kafka to somewhere else). This series of articles might help:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Also this talk shows it in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJtEacDX4Oc

Comment: thanks @Robin Moffatt , I would like to back in the  sql server jdbc connection into the image, for this which I guess it has to be in the docker file? what is the file name where i can see the connectors ?